# Anyone using BlueSnap's Google Analytics integration?

Tags: google-analytics, bluesnap

Here are **BlueSnap** (formerly **Plimus**)'s instructions for integrating Google Analytics in their hosted checkout pages:

> [How can I define my sales goals in Google Analytics?](https://cp.bluesnap.com/jsp/developer_3dparty_tracking.jsp)
>
> To set-up your sales goal and funnel, you’ll need to set-up 2 goals. Login to your Analytics account, find the relevant Website Profile and click on Edit.
> Set-up the following under the Goals section:

```
Goal 1: Purchase Successful:  
Goal URL: /BlueSnapBuyNow/Buynow Result Success  
Goal Funnel:  
Step 1: /BlueSnapBuyNow/Buynow$  
Step 2: /BlueSnapBuyNow/Buynow Step2  
Step 3: /BlueSnapBuyNow/buynow processing

Goal 2: Purchase Pending:  
Goal URL: /BlueSnapBuyNow/Buynow Result Pending  
Goal Funnel:  
Step 1: /BlueSnapBuyNow/Buynow$  
Step 2: /BlueSnapBuyNow/Buynow Step2  
Step 3: /BlueSnapBuyNow/buynow processing
```

Those goals didn't seem to work for me.
Is it because of the spaces and dollars?

For example:
[image: test]

**However**, Goal 1 started working when I changed the **Destination** to **/?thank-you=1** (the redirection back to my site which the users get upon purchasing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some updated documentation about how to set up the BlueSnap integration with Google Analytics:
http://support.bluesnap.com/docs/google-analytics

The URLs for the goals have been changed, as follows:

[URLs for GA goals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krDjT.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Dollar sign ("$") is used for Regular Expressions, and is used to mark *End of line*.

My guess is that the **Destination** drop-down should be set to *Regular expression* instead of *Equals to*, although it unfortunately does not seem to be specified in the setup guide you provided.

Also, depending on how your URLs are set up for your checkout process, "Result Success", "Step2" and "processing" might be suggested Step names for your Goal, and not be actual URLs.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't make any difference: http://i57.tinypic.com/2rmujo2.png

Comment: Edited my answer: Try setting "Result Success", "Step2" and "processing" as Goal Names instead of URLs.

Comment: Already did that too to no avail, but besides - do note if you do that then it's the very same URL all the time.

Comment: Actually, these are different URLs. First one ends with *Buynow* and nothing more (without QueryString, with capital letter), second one could be *Buynow?step=2* and last one is *buynow* (all lowercase). Unfortunately, I cannot access the BlueSnap documentation link you provided because it seems to require a Merchant Login.

Comment: The second link can only be "Buynow?step=2" if the instructions replaced the spaces with wildcards like (.*)
You can sign up [to their sandbox](https://sandbox.bluesnap.com/jsp/new_developer_sandbox.jsp), give them your tracking code, and use [test credit card numbers](http://docs.bluesnap.com/api/constant-values/test-credit-card-numbers).

Comment: My logs show the three steps' URLs actually exist (except $ which is probably regexp). But the goal URLs don't exist. Furthermore, there are other similar URLs which exist in my logs even though they're not documented.